# Are there biographies on Boris Shumyatsky that included his history before 1921?

Tags: communism, russian-revolution, russian-civil-war

[Zhang Guotao](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zhang_Guotao) in his memoir recounted his meeting with [Shumyatsky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boris_Shumyatsky) in 1921. The then King of Siberia was very busy but managed to treat Zhang with a private dinner in his home. After the dinner, Zhang wondered why Shumyatsky ate so well in the deep of a famine. Zhang's companion (Wedensky?) said something to the effect that equality must not be held absolutely because some comrades carried greater responsibility. Zhang replied, "Lenin eats only 3/4 pound of bread a day. How come Shumyatsky eats better than Lenin?"

Needless to say, Zhang, then 24 years old, was socially impaired, and Shumyatsky's hospitality produced the effect quite the opposite to what he had intended. Nevertheless, Shumyatsky's character is interesting and revealing. I wonder if there are detailed biographies on this person.

Comment: Source requests are difficult on H:SE, and biographies are almost never canonical sources.  (even auto-biographies have an implicit bias that renders them unsuitable for some uses).  Can you revise the question to one that asks for an authoritative answer?

Comment: The scientific mind does not accept authority in the sense in which religious people do. Ultimately it is the reader themselves who decide which piece of information from who is more likely to be true. It is hard to believe that in the 21st century there are people in the historical community still believe in "authority."

Comment: Hunh? Somewhere the wires are crossed; this has nothing do with religion.  SE is built on the notion of accepting an authoritative answer to questions.  There is discussion in Meta on the topic - SE tries to avoid "list questions" where all the answers are equally valid, or questions where only the OP finds any value in the answer.  I was just trying to help you to get a better answer to the question.  Good luck